# como guardar fecha y hora en mongodb desde laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, datetime, timestamp

Estoy intentando guardar fecha y hora en mi bd mongodb desde laravel 7. hasta ahora transformé el string que recibo a timestamp pero cuando guardo me cambia el dato insertando una fecha distinta. Muestro mi codigo asi me explico mejor:

```
 $time = strtotime("2010-01-15 22:12:22");
                
 $today = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($time);

$object->fecha_entrada = array("ts" => $today);
$result = $object->save();
```

El resultado en mi bd es este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me cambia la fecha y hora. No entiendo porque pasa esto.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que el tipo de dato devuelto por el método [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) de PHP, es el número de **segundos** transcurridos desde la fecha 01 de Enero de 1970 a las 00 horas UTC ([tiempo UNIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix)).

Pero el tipo de dato [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#date) en MongoDB almacena el número de **milisegundos** del mismo tiempo UNIX.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución consiste en multiplicar el valor devuelto por `strtotime()` por mil (1000), y de esta forma convertir los segundos en milisegundos:

```php
$time = strtotime("2010-01-15 22:12:22");
                
 $today = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($time * 1000); // multiplicamos por mil

$object->fecha_entrada = array("ts" => $today);
$result = $object->save();
```

El resultado al hacer la multiplicación es:

```js
2010-01-15T21:12:22.000Z
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: excelente!! muchas gracias